# One formula for summing a fixed number of rows in a single column but formula to expand dynamically for all varying columns

Tags: dynamic, sum, formula, offset, varying

I have a table whose number of rows remain fixed but its number of columns are varying (expand or contract) rightways.

I want to sum an array of 13 rows in each column with the result at the bottom of each column.

The tricky part however is to expand (or contract) that sum dynamically (with one formula, preferably not vba) according to the number of columns.

```
ie.
cell e18:        =sum(e4:e16) 
cell f18:        =sum(f4:f16)
cell g18:        =sum(g4:g16)
. 
.
cell n18:        =sum(n4:n16) for n number of columns.
```

Was thinking something like offsetting the variables in cell e18. ie.
cell e18:        =sum(offset(e4,0,0,1,n):offset(e16,0,0,1,n))
but excel does not recognize it :'(

Appreciate your help

Thank you!

Tried offsetting the variables in cell e18. ie.
cell e18:        =sum(offset(e4,0,0,1,n):offset(e16,0,0,1,n))
but excel does not recognize it :'(

Tried this formula =SUM(E4:INDEX(E4:E16,13)) for the first column and then replacing the variables e4 and e16 with offsets but without effect.